# Features Revert or Update

Tags: features

Just to clarify some attributes about features.

Revert will take what is in my code and add it to the database?

Update will take what is in my database and change the code?

What happens if I have overridden fields and want to omit them when copying the feature over to another site? Which one of the two from above will I use?

Answer (score -2):

When your feature is in overridden state and you want to omit the changes that you have done recently, you have to revert the feature.

You can use the user interface to revert the feature, or you can use  `drush fr feature_machine_name`.